# Shell script does not work when run as daemon

Tags: linux, shell

I got a simple script (to measure CPU overhead)

```
#!/bin/bash

WAIT=2
i=1
while :
do
    # Obtain the cpu usage
    top -n 1 > t.$i

    i=$(($i+1))
    sleep $WAIT

done
```

When I run it as

```
./Script.sh
```

It works as expected.

But when I run it as

```
./Script.sh&
```

it does nothing (files are not created).  What am I missing here?

Comment: is it related to `top`? have you tried it with something simpler?

Comment: Yes, other commands works fine! @KarolyHorvath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the line where you invoke top to be:

```
top -b -n 1 > t.$i
```

This enables batch mode - good call Karoly